# assigning multiple people to a single task in MSP

Tags: ms-project, multi-team

I am struggling with adding multiple resources to a task in MSP. 
So for example, I have 2 people that I need to attend a 1 hour workshop. 
Total work is 2 hours as I need both there for full duration. 
When I look at the % split that each person has been allocated it shows different Person 1 - 50% and Person 2 90%. 
Is this correct or should I make it 100%?

Comment: You can put the 100% manually.

Answer (score 1):

Project will assign the resources at their max units as defined in the Resource sheet.  If you want to assign resources at different amounts, you'll need to enter the units manually.  What are the resources' max units?

Answer (score 0):

It should be 100% for both of them as each person will be allocated for this workshop.